# Time the execution time for a function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to display the time it took for me to execute a particularly complex function as it is being executed.

Seems simple enough, but I can't make this happen.

I've implemented a simple Chronometer component, which works fine.

The idea is to start it right before I execute the algorithm and then stop it when it finishes. So basically my component would look like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = React.useState(false)
  // run the chronometer on click and start executing the algorithm
  const runAlgorithm = () => {
    setIsRunning(true)
    someAlgorithmThatWillTakeLong()
    // top once its done
    setIsRunning(false)
  }

 return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => runAlgorithm()}>Execute Algorithm and time it</button>
    <Chronometer isRunning={isRunning}/>
  </div>
  )
}
```

It is however ignored and I am not sure how to get both these things executing at once. Am I missing something?

Here is a working sample of what my code currently looks like:

```js
const Chronometer = ({isRunning}) => {
const [milisseconds, setMilliseconds] = React.useState(0)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        let interval = null
        if (isRunning) {
            interval = setInterval(() => {
                setMilliseconds((ms) => ms + 1)
            }, 1)
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval)
        }

        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
    }, [isRunning])

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Solution time:</h3>
            <h4>{milisseconds/100}</h4>
        </div>
    )
}

const someAlgorithmThatWillTakeLong = () => {
  for (let i=0; i<999999; i++) {
    // just run whatever
  }
  console.warn('done!')
  return
}

const App = () => {
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = React.useState(false)
  
  const runAlgorithm = () => {
    setIsRunning(true)
    someAlgorithmThatWillTakeLong()
     setIsRunning(false)
  }
  

  return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => runAlgorithm()}>Execute Algorithm and time it</button>
    <button style={{ width: 150 }} onClick={() => setIsRunning(!isRunning)}>{isRunning ? 'Stop' : 'Test chronometer'}</button>
    <Chronometer isRunning={isRunning}/>
  </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I would use performance.now() before and after running the algorithm. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Comment: Originally I wanted to actually time and see it going, but this is indeed simpler. Thanks @Patrick. You can put that in the answers to the question if you'd like.